# Is disk encryption (e. g. LUKS) reversed when having an encrypted disk image inside an encrypted partition with the same encryption password?

Tags: disk-encryption

Let's assume one has created an encrypted partition, e. g. with the LUKS standard. Then one creates a (virtual) disk image, e. g. for use by a virtual machine, containing an encrypted partition created by the same method and using the same encryption password. The disk image is stored inside the outer encrypted partition. I assume that a symmetric encryption is used.

Is it possible that the parts of the real disk which are occupied by the encrypted partion of the inside disk image are visible in plain text (or something close to that) as if no encryption was used (due to applying the same symmetric encryption method twice)?
If yes, in which particular configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. LUKS uses cryptography the right way so this isn't a risk. What you describe would only be a problem if both encryption layers did something really dumb, like both being naked AES-CTR with an unsalted hash of the password as the key.